# How to resolve "Internal server error" using mod_wsgi with web.py

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, web.py

I'm trying to configure mod_wsgi to work with a trivial web.py python script. I followed this cookbook: http://webpy.org/cookbook/mod_wsgi-apache

Every time i go to `https://<server>/appname/` chrome says `Internal Server Error`

Here are my config details:

in httpd.conf I have

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias /appname /var/www/webpy-app/cody.py/
Alias /appname /var/www/webpy-app/static/
AddType text/html .py

<Directory /var/www/webpy-app/>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location /appname>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authenication Required"
AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/conf/some_sample_users"
</Location>
```

Here is the code:

```
  import web

  urls = (
      '/.*', 'hello',
      )

  class hello:
      def GET(self):
          return "Hello, world."

  application = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
```

I checked the error logs but didnt find much in there:

```
[Wed Oct 09 02:24:50 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Oct 09 02:24:55 2013] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed Oct 09 02:24:55 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Oct 09 02:24:55 2013] [warn] module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Oct 09 02:24:55 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Oct 09 02:24:55 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Oct 09 02:24:55 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.6 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
```

What modifications would I need to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong for a start:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /appname /var/www/webpy-app/cody.py/
Alias /appname /var/www/webpy-app/static/
```

The Alias directive takes precedence over WSGIScriptAlias. You have them for the same mount point, so Alias wins. I would suggest commenting out Alias for a start.

As well as that, having a trailing slash on second argument and not the first when mounting at sub URL can cause issues. Use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /appname /var/www/webpy-app/cody.py
```

Next problem is:

```
[Wed Oct 09 02:24:55 2013] [warn] module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
```

This indicates you have:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

listed twice in different places in Apache configuration, or you have managed to include a configuration file twice that has it listed.

Fix those issues first and then edit you question with updated information.

Comment: fixing those brought more relevant answers in play. I installed mod_wsgi using yum, however, it used the default python2.6. Now I need to remove that and install mod_wsgi from source so that it can use python2.7

Answer (score 0):

I follow [this tutorial](https://www.hyperink.com/blog/?p=13) which is complete step to run web.py without .htaccess,
but remember when you copy paste the python code you must watch the indentation, because it will show Internal server error as well. this is how httpd.conf looks like

```
<VirtualHost _default_ *:80> 
ServerAdmin admin@project.com 
DocumentRoot /var/www/project.com/public_html/ 
ErrorLog /var/www/project.com/logs/error.log 
CustomLog /var/www/project.com/logs/access.log combined  
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/project.com/production/main.py 
Alias /static /var/www/project.com/public_html 
AddType text/html .py 
WSGIDaemonProcess www-data threads=15 
WSGIProcessGroup www-data  
    <Directory /var/www/project.com/production/> 
        Order deny,allow 
        Allow from all 
        Options +FollowSymLinks 
        Options -Indexes 
    </Directory>      
</VirtualHost>
```

with main.py as index file